# Complex logic gate?

Tags: python, boolean, logic, boolean-logic

So I've made a Python module that adds all seven logic gates (NOT, OR, AND, NAND, NOR, XOR, XNOR.)

Please note that it does not look like

```
a AND b
```

it instead looks like

```
And(a, b)
```

In  a program I'm trying to make, I need a logic gate with three inputs: A, B and C. the gate should return whatever A is **if** C is false. However, if C is true, it should return whatever B is. It does **not** matter if A and B are the same. I don't want to use actual if's.

Comment: What you describe is a one-bit multiplexer (MUX), where C is the select  (SEL). And it is unclear what exactly you're asking of us.

Comment: Are you trying to compose the gate you want from the gates you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to create a multiplexer gate from the logic gates you have defined, here is a great article on the subject: http://improve.dk/creating-multiplexers-using-logic-gates/.

Basically, you do this:

```
def MUX(A, B, C):
    return OR(AND(A, C), AND(B, NOT(C)))
```

In Python notation, this would look like `(A & C) | (B & ~C)`.

If `C` is `True`, the result is `A`. If `C` is `False`, the result is `B`.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I cannot thank you enough!! this will TOTALLY help me!

Comment: Glad to hear it

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
def MUX(A, B, C):
    return B if C else A
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this : 
[image: here]

Here you have your C instant of SEL. The out is your MULTIPLEXER return

so in python

```
def MULTIPLEXER(A,B,C):
   if(C):
      return B
   else:
      return A
```